# Python: Finding the keys in an unfamiliar json object

Tags: python, json

G'day All,

After my last question I have been teaching myself to use the json module and have come to this problem.

Given an unfamiliar array:

```
{"Age": 20, "Nickname": "Jim", "Name": "Fred", "Height": 180}
```

How do I find the keys in this object?

Thanks,

Comment: `Given an unfamiliar array:` it's a dict not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = {"Age": 20, "Nickname": "Jim", "Name": "Fred", "Height": 180}
>>> d.keys()
['Age', 'Nickname', 'Name', 'Height']
```

Or, even more simply, if you plan to iterate:

```
>>> for k in d:
...     print k
... 
Age
Nickname
Name
Height
```

Comment: You're kidding me!  I've been reading for for the last 45 mins and was resigned to something with with a dozen lines of code as others problems have been more complex than mine.  Thank-you!! (and please excuse my ignorance)